# c++ encryption with rotation

Tags: c++, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm having some issues in creating a function that encrypts a word using a rotation number the user inputs. Here is what I have so far:

```
string encryptWord(string word, int num)
{
  string newWord;
  newWord = word;
  for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
      newWord[i] = tolower(word[i]);
      if((word[i] >= 'a') && (word[i] <= 'z'))
        {
          newWord[i] = word[i] + (num % 26);
          if(newWord[i] > 'z')
            newWord[i] = newWord[i] - 26;

        }
    }
  return newWord;

}
```

now in my main when I test it out with

```
cout << encryptWord("xyz", 6);
```

the output I get is: de

Similarly, for decryption I have

```
string decryptRotWord(string word, int num)
{
  string newWord;
  num = num % 26;
  int index;
  for(int i = 0; i < word[i]; i++)
    {
      newWord[i] = tolower(word[i]);
      if(word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')
        {
          index = word[i] - num;
          if(index < 'a')
              index = index + 26;
          newWord[i] = index;
        }
    }
  return newWord;

}
```

however, for this one, it does not output anything when I test with

```
cout << decryptRotWord("vdds", 2);
```

Comment: `'z' + 6 > CHAR_MAX`. Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of signed integral overflow.

Comment: This is why I find TDD faster for developing code with any logic in it.

Answer (score 0):

In your decrypt function, I think you have a mistake on the loop end condition:

`for(int i = 0; i < word[i]; i++)`

As in the encrypt function, you should iterate over length

`for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)`

Comment: I modified my decryption function to end loop through word.length() but I'm still not getting an output. And as for the encrypt, what do you mean by iterate over length?

Answer (score 0):

When your `for` loop arrives to the letter `'z'`, it does `'z' + 6`. But that goes beyond the max length of a `char` (127). You get an undefined behavior from that.

You should implement a way of starting to count from `'a'` whenever you check the encryption goes beyond `'z'`.

For the decryption, same as mentioned before, you want to test :

```
i < word.length()
```